# How to configure JIRA admin on a Web server

Tags: jira

I already have a website running and want to install JIRA Server on it. So how do I add a sub directory to my main website, example [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) is my actual website so want [www.mywebsite.com/Jira](http://www.mywebsite.com/Jira) how do I achieve this?

I had downloaded the windows JIRA Installer and ran it locally connecting to the database hosted on my server and it worked using localhost(http://localhost:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa) however now I want to access it through the web link i.e base URL.

I am new to this so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: People down voting due to the lack of clarification in the questions @userhi

Comment: @userhi why do you want to know the reason?  it isn't your question.

Comment: @Amy Dont you think you could ask me for clarification if my question was not complete?

Comment: @mano I questioned his standing to ask such a question.  *You* have standing to ask, because it is *your* question; *he*, presumably, does not (which is why I asked).  But to directly answer your question, no one is obligated to provide clarification, nor is it rude not to.

Answer (score 0):

Well I understand you do have a domain and you want to run your JIRA with context path /jira un that domain. If that's the case, you may need to consider running your JIRA behind proxy. Take a look at Atlassian documentation since it contains all the information that you need for this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html